# The integral of a function's square root

Tags: calculus, integration, graphing-functions

Let's take a known polynomial function $f$, which is positive bounded in $[a,b]$. If I know $\int_a^bf(x)dx$, can I calculate or at least estimate $\int_a^b\sqrt{f(x)}dx$?
Is it possible to calculate $\int_0^a\sqrt{(b^2-x^2)(a^2-x^2)}dx$?

Comment: The first integral won't help you get the second, which will almost always only be [numerically approximable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration). Just in case this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), was there a specific $a,\,b,\,f$ for which you wanted $\int_a^b\sqrt{f(x)}dx$?

Comment: a general answer is fine with me, but the specific a=0.49, b=0.7

Comment: Using Simpson's rule, I get ~0.123323495140356298072

Comment: 1/2 With $x=at,\,k=a/b$ your integral is$$\color{limegreen}{\int_0^1k^2b^3\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}dt}.$$Wolfram Alpha experiments suggest this is$$k^{-1}(1+k^2)b^2E(k)-k^{-1}(1-k^2)b^2K(k)$$(where $E(k):=\int_0^1\sqrt{\tfrac{1-k^2t^2}{1-t^2}}dt$ ($K(k):=\int_0^1\tfrac{dt}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}$) is the complete elliptic integral of the [second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind) ([first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind)) kind),

Comment: 2/2 which would be$$\color{red}{\int_0^1\left[k^{-1}(1+k^2)b^2\sqrt{\tfrac{1-k^2t^2}{1-t^2}}-\tfrac{k^{-1}(1-k^2)b^2}{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(1-k^2t^2)}}\right]dt}.$$ However, it's not obvious why the red expression equals the green one.

Comment: For quadratics, there is a known closed form results. I am not so sure for quartics.